# Ms Access 2007 record set not auto filling into textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a module with a procedure inside that looks like this:

```
Public Sub OpenRecordset()

Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("QOff2")
qdf.Parameters(0).Value = [Forms]![Form]![Text10]

Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim StrBusinesses As String

Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then
MsgBox ("No businesses exist for this Customer")
Exit Sub
Else
rs.MoveFirst
End If
StrBusinesses = ""
Do While Not rs.EOF
StrBusinesses = StrBusinesses & rs!Fnam & ", "
rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
StrBusinesses = Left(StrBusinesses, Len(StrBusinesses) - 2)
Forms!Form.Badge = StrBusinesses
Set rs = Nothing



End Sub
```

I am trying to get this module to input the query results into a textbox (forms!form.badge), but I can't seem to get it to do it like my 5 other dlookup functions. When I open up the module and push the green play button, it shows up on the correct textbox but also shows up on the other records as well. It also doesn't show up automatically, nor does it update as you enter in the parameters. Isn't a module supposed to help autofil numerous variables into a text box in place of dlookup for multiple values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. If Forms!Form!Badge is an unbound textbox, a value assigned to it will be shown identically for all records. 
To individualize, you will need a lookup function which takes the ID or other unique value of the record as parameter(add to textbox):

```
=LookupBadges([Forms]![Form]![Text10])


Public Function LookupBadges(ByVal Value As Variant) As Variant

    Dim db As Database
    Dim qd As QueryDef    
    Dim rs As Recordset

    Dim Businesses As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qd = db.QueryDefs("QOff2")

    qd.Parameters(0).Value = Nz(Value)
    Set rs = qd.OpenRecordset
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            Businesses = Businesses & rs!Fnam.Value & ", "
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    rs.Close

    Businesses = Left(Businesses, Len(Businesses) - 2)
    LookupBadges = Businesses

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set qd = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Would this work like a dlookup, and how does the module auto fill in the numbers with out pushing the green play button? @gustav. Thank you.

Comment: You will either use DLookup as is (look in the on-line help for syntax) or create your own LookupBadges function if you need more than DLookup can provide. When the form is opened, the values will be fetched - no need for a play button.

Comment: when I use your code, it says #name error. Can you explain a little bit more about create my own LookupBadges function? Do you mean that I need to create this lookup from the query?

Comment: No, I mean that if DLookup should not fit your needs, you can write your own similar function that will return one value determined by the parameters fed to it. LookupBadges is just a work title for such function.

Comment: I am not understanding the function and how to write the lookupbadges, can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: for Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset, do we need to set the openrecordset somewhere? I tried adding Public Sub back in but I don't think that is right.  Thank you.

Comment: It is being set in the function. This you copy and paste into a code module. You don't need anything in the form other than setting the controlsourc for the textbox to:    =LookupBadges([Forms]![YourFormName]![Text10])

Comment: I am asking because I get a object not defined error with that statement highlighted when I put that in the textbox

Comment: Well, yes, you must replace YourFormName with the actual name of your form.